# Example of using CopyToDataTable in F#

Tags: f#

I'm looking for a simple example of using CopyToDataTable ([DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in a F# program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open System.Data

let sourceTable = new DataTable()
sourceTable.Columns.Add() |> ignore
sourceTable.Rows.Add(1) |> ignore
sourceTable.Rows.Add(2) |> ignore
sourceTable.Rows.Add(3) |> ignore

let source = sourceTable.Rows |> Seq.cast<DataRow>
let table = source.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: This fails with:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Additional information: The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: Actually I was hoping for an example that yielded a non-empty table ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On Mono (at least on Mac OS) you need to manually reference the `DataSetExtensions` assembly. E.g., following Mark's answer, in the interpreter you need:

```
#r "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"

let source = Seq.empty<DataRow>
let table = source.CopyToDataTable()
```